# MySQL refuses to start on my Debian 10 server after a botched control panel installation attempt

Tags: mysql, debian-buster, exit-code

#### Context

After two failed control panel installation (tinycp and cloudpanel) attempts and a restart the MySQL service (Community version 8.0.27) is not starting.

When trying to restart the service, it aborts with an exit code.
The error log file is not being written to after I shutdown the machine yesterday, the file (`/var/log/mysql/error.log`) has not been touched since.

I cannot find the `my.cnf` file as well. By running `journalctl -xe`, I get a message that it is missing:

```
mysql-systemd-start[774]: MySQL configuration not found at /etc/mysql/my.cnf. Please install one.
```

I may have inadvertently damaged my system by trying to purge and auto-remove the partially installed control panels (the installation failed due to dependencies).

Unfortunately, the last dump file is a bit old.

#### Things I've tried

- I tried restarting the MySQL service, but it aborts.

#### Question

### How can I recover from this situation? In case I need to re-install MySQL how can I make sure I keep the existing databases?

Update:
Thank you. Sorry about half-finished edit. It timed out and I was interrupted as well.
However, Success...after spending one whole day on this.
I copied over an old configuration file from a backup [after having created a mysql subfolder as well.]
At first, no joy. On querying the status of mysql service, it said cannot write to the error file due to permission problem:
[MY-010187] [Server] Could not open file '/var/log/mysqld.log' for error logging: Permission denied
This file was also missing. Created it and gave it the permissions.
The server started, but could not access the databases via phpMyAdmin [but could do with DBeaver?.]
Lastly, Webmin reported that:
"connect to server at 'localhost' failed error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)' Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!"
I just deleted the line about sockets in the config file and restarted the server. It seems that it is back to its previous state.
So, success of some sorts. However, by purging those unfinished leftover, it appears that many of the libraries in the system have also been deleted. So, for example, Visual Studio Code is non-functioning now.
But, now I can do a back up, just in case...
Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: Have you tried searching for a default `.my.cnf` file on the web and pasting that in place of `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`?

Comment: Thank you. No, however, I copied over an old configuration file from a backup [after having created a mysql subfolder as well.]

Comment: And what was the result? Feel free to [edit] your question to add that information